# ¿Cómo puedo salir de un método en Python?

Tags: python, recursión

Tengo el siguiente método en una clase llamada `Registro` en Python:

```
    def registroProveedor(self):
    os.system("cls")
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print("         Supertienda LA COBANERITA")
    print("   --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS PROVEEDORES ---")
    codProv = int(input("Código del proveedor: "))
    #---Se verifica que el código de proveedor no esté ya en uso.
    if lstProveedor:
        for proveedores in lstProveedor:
            if proveedores[0] == codProv:
                print(proveedores[0])
                print("--- Ya existe un proveedor registrado con ese código. ---")
                print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar, e intente nuevamente...")
                msvcrt.getch()
                Registro.registroProveedor(self)
            else:
                nitProv = int(input("NIT del proveedor: "))
                nomProv = input("Nombre del proveedor: ")
                direcProv = input("Dirección del proveedor: ")
                telProv = input("No. teléfono del proveedor: ")
    else:
        nitProv = int(input("NIT del proveedor: "))
        nomProv = input("Nombre del proveedor: ")
        direcProv = input("Dirección del proveedor: ")
        telProv = input("No. teléfono del proveedor: ") 
    
    proveedor = registroP.Proveedor(codProv, nitProv, nomProv, direcProv, telProv)
    proveedor.registrarProveedor()
    lstProveedor.append(proveedor.lstProv)
```

Y estoy teniendo problemas con la recursividad, ya que si en la  validación de `codProv` existe ya un valor registrado, me llamaría de nuevo a esa función para intentar de nuevo hacer una validación.

Al registrar un nuevo proveedor teniendo una lista vacía, o una lista con varios objetos proveedor dentro de ella con `codProv` diferentes, no tengo ningún problema. El problema surge al encontrar un `codProv` que ya está siendo usado, porque vuelve a llamar a `Registro.registroProveedor(self)`, y si bien es cierto que me pide los datos de nuevo, cuando en teoría debería mandar los datos para su almacenamiento, lo que pasa es que sale de esa función que se volvió a llamar, y regresa de nuevo al `Registro.registroProveedor(self)`.

En pocas palabras, se apilan ambas funciones, y al llamar a una, cuando terminan sus instrucciones, la primera función que se llamó sigue corriendo en segundo plano, y me vuelve a pedir los datos, cosa que en anteriores lenguajes no me pasaba.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo salir de ese método sin que se apilen ambas funciones?
o bien ¿qué podría cambiar en mi recursividad para que al llamara de nuevo una función, la anterior no siga corriendo en segundo plano.

Comment: pon un `break`, recuerda que la recursión no es buena y existen otras formas de hacerlo

Comment: ¿En dónde podría poner el break?

Comment: al final de pedir todos los datos

Comment: ¿Dentro del if anidado, dentro del if principal o fuera de ambos bucles?

Comment: en el if anidado despues de `telProv`

Comment: Justo acabo de intentarlo, incluso dejando comentado el `Registro.registroProveedor(self)` pero salta a la parte del else del if principal y me vuelve a solicitar el NIT

Comment: Tu problema no requiere recursión.

Comment: Bien, puse un break para ambas condiciones del if anidado y sin recursión, y ahora funciona muy bien. Ya regresa a la función anterior a la de registro de proveedores. Ahora el detalles el siguiente: al volver a entrar a la función como una "nueva vez" me permite ingresar un nuevo proveedor con un código ya existente, teniendo así 2 proveedores con el mismo código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es continuar pidiendo el código de proveedor hasta que aparezca uno válido (no registrado previamente). La estructura general de la solución es encerrar todo en un `while True:` y agregar un `break` condicional para escapar cuando el código este bueno.

He reorganizado el código:

```
def registroProveedor(self):
    while True:
        os.system("cls")
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        print("         Supertienda LA COBANERITA")
        print("   --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS PROVEEDORES ---")
        codProv = int(input("Código del proveedor: "))
        # ---Se verifica que el código de proveedor no esté ya en uso.
        if lstProveedor:
            for proveedores in lstProveedor:
                if proveedores[0] == codProv:
                    print(proveedores[0])
                    print("--- Ya existe un proveedor registrado con ese código. ---")
                    print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar, e intente nuevamente...")
                    msvcrt.getch()
                    continue

        break

    nitProv = int(input("NIT del proveedor: "))
    nomProv = input("Nombre del proveedor: ")
    direcProv = input("Dirección del proveedor: ")
    telProv = input("No. teléfono del proveedor: ")
```

Lo primero es reemplazar la llamada recursiva por un `continue`. Este provoca que se repita el ciclo `while True:`, pidiendo nuevamente el código, que es el efecto que buscas.

Si la lista de proveedores no existe, o el código del proveedor es válido, caemos en el `break` que nos saca del ciclo infinito.

Lo que queda es pedir el resto de los datos, sin importar si la lista de proveedores existe o no.

Comment: Sucedió algo, y es que aunque se encuentre un código que ya está ocupado, de igual forma pide los siguientes datos y permite crear un nuevo Proveedor con el código repetido.

Comment: @OscarAnibal. Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)